# Count timestamps with offset between two databases in a view

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to count time stamps between two databases but one has overlapping time stamps, due to not my design flaw.

```
SELECT date(time + INTERVAL 8 HOUR) as day, COUNT(DISTINCT comment)
FROM  news.data
GROUP BY day
    UNION ALL
SELECT date(time + INTERVAL 8 HOUR) as day, COUNT(DISTINCT comment)
FROM`news-backup`.`data`
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY year(day) desc, day(day) DESC
LIMIT 20
```

What seems to happen, there are some timestamps in range of both databases so they produce separate counts for certain dates. So it would give count for TODAY from news and news-backup

```
EX:
date      count
2013-1-15  10
2013-1-15  13
2013-1-14  8
2013-1-13  15
```

What I want is

```
EX:
date      count
2013-1-15  23
2013-1-14  8
2013-1-13  15
```

Here is a kicker, I need it in a view, so there are some limitations with that (no subqueries allowed). Thoughts? And no I cannot change the data dump sequence that happens between to DBs

Comment: No sure, I try putting subquerrys in a VIEW and it gives me an error 
"SQL ERROR 1349: ciews select contains a suquerry in the from clause"

Comment: Sorry . . . the documentation is really misleading.  In one place it says subqueries are allowed, and in another place that they are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put a subquery in a view, but you can put a view in a view.

So:

```
create view1 as 
    SELECT date(time + INTERVAL 8 HOUR) as day, 'current' as which, COUNT(DISTINCT comment) as cnt
    FROM  news.data
    GROUP BY day
        UNION ALL
    SELECT date(time + INTERVAL 8 HOUR) as day, 'backup' as which, COUNT(DISTINCT comment) as cnt
    FROM`news-backup`.`data`
    GROUP BY day, which
```

I'm not sure what you logic for combining them is:

```
create view2 as
    select day, max(cnt)  -- sum(cnt)?  prefer current or backup?
    from view1
    group by day
    ORDER BY day desc
```

The documentation that bans subqueries is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-view.html).  Be sure to search for "The SELECT statement cannot contain".

If you have a table of all the dates, the following "absurd" SQL might work:

```
select c.date,
       coalesce( (select count(distinct comment) from news.data where date(time + INTERVAL 8 HOUR) = c.date),
                 (select count(distinct comment) from news_backup.data where date(time + INTERVAL 8 HOUR) = c.date)
               ) as NumComments
from calendar c
```

This version is assuming you want the "new" first, then the backup.  If you want the sum, then you would add them.

Comment: @eggyal . . . Read down further, where is says "The SELECT statement cannot contain a subquery in the FROM clause."  Bad documentation.

Comment: any other possible solutions without double views?

Comment: seems like there is no easy way out of this